# How to Export Selected MySQL Data to an Excel Spread Sheet

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am currently working on the export side of my site to allow users the ability to view data held on a MySQL database. Currently I have a working solution that passes all the data selected in a query to a .CSV file.

The problem I am having is that I want to be able to let users select their own data and then be able to export the displayed data to a spread sheet rather than the whole table.

My first thought to solving this problem would be to perhaps store the query executed into a variable and then include it when using the export script.

Would this method be recommended or am I straying on the wrong path? If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Also if this question is not suitable, please can you justify why. All feedback will be useful for future posts.

Comment: have you looked at the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914957/creating-csv-with-php

Comment: @LiamSorsby I have looked at the question that you have suggested. From what I gather, would it be an idea to put selected data into an array and then pass that information on when exporting?

Comment: Such a solution should already exist. Please use a search engine (maybe try the terms: "php mysql csv export"). If you have a programming question you should ask it. But asking the user for the SQL query to start an export sounds like the worst solution.

Comment: It would only be a god idea to fetch the data into an array then pass the array on to export if you want to use a lot of memory and increase the processing time. Do you want a csv file or an Excel file?

Comment: @feeela I think you have probably got the wrong impression from my question, perhaps maybe my grammar or poor explaining. Users would enter for example a name into a search and then the MySQL query would return the data found in the table. I would then want to export the returned data to a csv file.

Comment: @MarkBaker Originally I wanted to pass on to a excel file. Whilst doing my research I found that passing to a CSV would be more conventional than Excel. Excel has horrible auto formatting and for the basic data I'm passing through, CSV satisfies my intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use phpexcel library :

this full example I wrote it before

```
<?php
include("classes/PHPExcel.php");
    set_time_limit(0);

$sql="Select * from datbase";

// Execute the database query
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Instantiate a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
// Initialise the Excel row number
$rowCount = 1; 
// Iterate through each result from the SQL query in turn
// We fetch each database result row into $row in turn
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    // Set cell An to the "name" column from the database (assuming you have a column called name)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['user_id']); 
    // Set cell Bn to the "age" column from the database (assuming you have a column called age)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['email'])); 

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('c'.$rowCount,$row['email']); 

     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('d'.$rowCount,$row['email']); 
     $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('e'.$rowCount,$row['email']); 
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('f'.$rowCount,$row['email']); 
    // Increment the Excel row counter
    $rowCount++;      

} 

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
// Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
$objWriter->save('all_data.xlsx'); 



?>
```

For more information ad examples :
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into this. I have been recommended phpexcel in the past by other users